# Is there any safe way to convert tabs to spaces in multiple files?

Tags: tabs, spaces

Is there any safe way to automate this process for multiple files? By safe I want that this will not break the code or introduce some kind of weird side effects that will manifest exactly when you don't want it in production.

I know about http://man.cx/expand. Is this method truly safe?

Answer (score 1):

`expand` is pretty good, but I seem to recall it can get tricked in some conditions / for some languages, so for safety I'd have to assume "not truly".

Hopefully, however, your source code has plenty of tests before it goes to Production to demonstrate its full functionality and correctness.

Alternatively / additionally, if you're compiling or producing bytecode (e.g. Java), you could probably do a binary comparison of the artefacts to prove equivalence between the original and that produced from the de-tabbed source code.

Comment: Hmm, even harder perhaps.

Though I'd say the various [minification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_%28programming%29) libraries actually do a good job of this for JS - you could try comparing the minified outputs.

For HTML, it "should" be irrelevant, unless... not.. e.g. you're in a `<pre>` block, or `CDATA`... eek..